# Regex to find strings separated by comma, and then add quotes?

Tags: regex, csv, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and have a CSV file with 1200 tax rates in this format:

```
Code,Country,State,Zip/Post Code,Rate,default
US-NY-10001-Rate 1,US,NY,10001,0.08875,
....
```

I need a regex to find each value separated by a comma so I can then wrap quotes around it.

Is this possible?

Comment: What if the values have comma's in them?

Comment: @hwnd: None of them do in this case.

Comment: @Lost did you're looking for this http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/24 ?

Answer (score 15):

Find the following regular expression (using [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)):

```
([^,\n]+)
```

and replace it with:

```
"\1"
```

[image]

Comment: This is close, but it wraps quotes around values separated by a space as well ... like `'US-NY-10002-Rate' '1'` when it should be `'US-NY-10002-Rate 1'` - the first value is the only one with a space if that matters.

Comment: @Lost, Then, instead of `\s`, use `\n`.

Comment: +1 for short-and-sweet solution with nice screenshot :)

Comment: Elegant and beautiful. +1