# Regex to find and replace single quotation marks in strings separated by a comma and enclosed in quotes

Tags: regex, perl, csv, replace, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and I have a CSV file which contains single quotation:

**Input:**

```
"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"
"Cakes", "5" Carrots", "Pineapples'", ""Eggs"", "Apple 5" and 10""
...
```

Using regular expressions I would like to "neutralise" but not remove the out of place single quotations (eg. `5" Carrots`, `""Eggs""`) and apostrophes (eg. `Pineapples'`).

By neutralise I specifically mean to place `\"` in front of each single quotation/apostrophe so the output is:

**Output:**

```
"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"
"Cakes", "5\"" Carrots", "Pineapples\"'", "\""Eggs\""", "Apple 5\"" and 10\"""
...
```

**Progress so far:**
I think I have 2 pieces needed to solve the puzzle.

Firstly, I can find and replace the quotations for each individual field on its own using the regular expression `(".*)(["])(.*")`
Example:

*Input:* `"Hello 5" World"` *Find:* `(".*)(["])(.*")` *Replace:* `\1\\\""\3`
*Output:* `"Hello 5\"" World"`. To reproduce this you need to have regex and wrap options selected on the sublime find and replace toolbar.

Secondly, I can find each field in a csv file (opened up in Sublime) using the regular expression `([^,\n]+)`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741214/regex-to-find-strings-separated-by-comma-and-then-add-quotes) previous question for more info.

The question is how can I use both of these techniques (or others if needed) to get a regex to find and a regex to replace each field which has a single quotation marks (i.e. precede it by `\"`).

If you don't think this can be done through sublime and regular expressions it would be great if you could suggest a way to do this.

**Further Details:**
For absolute clarity a solution should contain a regular express that finds each field in the CSV file (opened in sublime) that has a single quotation mark in. Then there should be a regular expression that inserts before each quotation mark the string `\"`.

Comment: I think if this `"5" Carrots"` is a valid field, then there can be no comma's within quotes right? Otherwise it could be this `",5," Carrots", ` making the comma the only valid delimiter.

Comment: @sln has a good point. Would `",5","Something"` be valid? Notice the the command inside the first group, preceding `5`.

Comment: @Erutan409 Yes `",5","Something"` would be a valid field. But the comma doesn't need to be "treated" (have `\"`) placed in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd perform three steps in solving your problem:

1. Perform this find/replace [regex](http://bit.ly/1lT9Lze) to create barriers for groups of text

`"([\S\h]*?)"((?:,|\h*$))` replace with `[<]$1[>]$2`

2. Then find your offending double quotes with this find/replace [regex](http://bit.ly/1lTb8Oy)

`"|(?=')` replace with `\\"`

3. Then, finally, replace your barriers back to where they were with this [regex](http://bit.ly/1lTa6lv)

`\[[<>]\]` replace with `"`

Edit:

I just updated step 2.  I think I'm understanding your problem, correctly.  If not, please explain why and I'll adjust the regular expressions accordingly.

Comment: That is amazing - thank you sooo much! The only adjustment is that in step 2 the replacement regex would of `\\"\"` seems to work.

Comment: The only thing I have now just realised in my stupidity is that when it is an apostraphe the adjustment would needs to be to place `\''` - is there any way of adjusting it to implement this when on an apostrophe but keep it as is for quotation marks? If it's a massive change don't worry the code could be run twice instead for each case. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: There would need to be an additional step; more than likely before step 3.  So, I'd modify step 2 to only replace the first part `"` -> `\\"\"` (as you pointed out in your first comment).  Then add another step to find the single quotes `(?<!\\)'` -> `\''`.  The lookbehind in the aforementioned rexeg is an assumption on my part.  Drop it if you don't care about potential preceding backslahes when matching single quotes.

Comment: Ah ok. Just tested it now. For the new step adding an extra backslash seems to make it work ( `(?<!\\)'` -> `\\''` ). Again thanks so much for your help. FYI for context - i'm doing this to pre-process data to load into amazon redshift.

Comment: You're welcome. An upvote and/or even an accepted answer would be cool, too ;)

Comment: Done and i'm not yet cool enough to upvote :( Btw I thought I'd ask - is using regex really the best way to clean this kind of data? I feel like there is something better out but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Subjective.  Regex is usually considered a high-overhead approach to solving these kinds of problems when it can (simply) be done in other ways.  For what you're doing, using a series of regular expressions to accomplish a manual task (assuming that it'll always be manual), is probably the most efficient way of automating the your end solution.  Especially inside of an IDE, unless you want to write a plugin.  My two cents.

Comment: That is good to know - can definitely see the overhead with regex (working with it on a 1gb file in ultraedit) but like you said not much else that can do it so efficiently. Thanks again for the help. aj